# delphi read from TMemorystream without position change

Tags: delphi

i have a TMemory stream that is filled from a proccess, i need to read an other part of it real time.when i use this code :

```
for i := 0 to j do
begin
    FOutputStream.position:=i * 194
    stream4.CopyFrom(FOutputStream,   194 );
end;
```

it return wrong data because the writer process change the position.
so i decided to use Memory property

```
stream4.CopyFrom( PByte(FOutputStream.Memory)[ i * 194 ] , 194) );
```

but i got this error

> [DCC Error] Unit1.pas(640): E2010 Incompatible types: 'TStream' and
>   'Byte'

how can i handle this error?

Comment: Writer process can change memory location too, so then you will have AV. You should use Mutex or other synchronize primitive to protect shared resource (`TMemoryStream`) between reader and writer.

Comment: @zed is TMemoryStream.position and TMemoryStream.memory have one pointer? i mean if i change the position then memory change too or both must set separately??!

Comment: With ‘Filled from a progress’ do you really mean ‘process’ or do you mean ‘thread’?

Comment: No, Position and Memory is a different things, but they both can be changed by Writer.

Comment: @R.Hoek the process that fill the memory run in ui thread and i read from it in an other thread.

Comment: Well, then you really really need to take care of thread safe access of the resource like @zed said. Create a ‘mutex’ or ‘criticalsection’ or maybe ‘tmrewsync’ to be sure the stream cannot be modified while you are reading data from it. NOTE: this has to be done from both the reading and the writing thread!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot use `CopyFrom` directly  in this case, because that requires a stream, and you have a pointer.

You could solve this by creating a stream object that wrapped the memory owned by another memory stream. However that is needlessly complex. You merely need to call `WriteBuffer`.

```
stream4.WriteBuffer(PByte(FOutputStream.Memory)[i * 194] , 194);
```

I presume that you know this, but since you are operating from different threads when reading from and writing to the memory stream, you need to make sure that these actions account for any potential thread safety issues.

Comment: is this write on pointer position or write on the end of the stream !?

Comment: Stream write starts from current position. If it didn't streams would be kinda useless.

Comment: is there any way to append new bytes to end of stream without changing pointer position ?

Comment: Sure. Make a note of the current position. Seek to the end. Write data. Then seek back to the original position.